# sed doesn't work with empty input

Tags: sed

```
 $ echo '' | sed -e '$a\new content' | cat -n
     1
     2  new content
```

but if we don't put new-line, there's no output at all:

```
$ echo -n '' | sed -e '$a\new content' | cat -n
$
```

Another questions (even more important) are: Can it be worked around? How?

Comment: the work-around is to use `echo 'new content' | whatever else you're trying to do` ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, think of multiple files some of them can be empty and others are not, but you're to process each of them and better using the same command

Answer (score 2):

According to
[Eric Pement](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/THANKS#n19), this is
[not possible with sed](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.sed.user/663).
However awk can do this easily

```sh
$ printf '' | awk '{print} END {print "new content"}'
new content
```

Comment: these links are dead